# Is there a table of contents out there for the seifim of the Shulchan Aruch and Mishna Berura?

Tags: shulchan-aruch, mishnah-berurah

The idea of an **index** to the Shulchan Aruch and Mishna Berura is quite common. I'm interested in a **table of contents** that goes through each siman of Shulchan Aruch and identifies the topic of each se'if. I'm also interested in the parallel idea for the seifim ketanim of the Mishna Berura and Biur Halacha.

Do such things exist? I haven't found anything looking online.

Comment: [Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A) has for each **simman** of the Shulchan Aruch. Not sure where to get for seifim,  and I doubt you'll find for the thousands of seifim ketanim of the Mishnah Berurah. Maybe for the Beur Halacha.

Comment: Some editions of mishna berura have an appendix in the back called "שינון הלכה". Meant as a reviewing (chazara) tool, it does seem to approximate a table of contents for shulchan aruch OC, rama, mishna brura and biur halacha.